# Cross compiled C Windows libcurl doesn't get linked correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, libcurl

I am currently trying to cross compile libcurl in c for Windows 32x on Ubuntu 64x 14.04. After a bit of research I followed these steps:

1) Download library from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

2) Go into extracted libcurl folder and execute:

`./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/ --enable-static --disable-shared`

3) Execute: make

4) Execute: sudo make install

Then I added these include statements:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // Needed for curl
#include <windows.h> // Windows API
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode response;

    char url[] = "someurl.com";

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) 
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); //set url options

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        response = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(response != CURLE_OK)
        {
          //Do something
        }

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Now I tried to compile my code with following arguments:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o main.exe -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lcurl
```

The compiler returned following error code:

```
/tmp/ccebLf6U.o:main.c:(.text+0x336): Not defined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
/tmp/ccebLf6U.o:main.c:(.text+0x365): Not defined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
/tmp/ccebLf6U.o:main.c:(.text+0x372): Not defined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
/tmp/ccebLf6U.o:main.c:(.text+0x3f4): Not defined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Has someone an idea on how to fix this ?

**[EDIT]**

Something really interesting I stumbled upon is that if you call curl-config you get a bunch of compiler options.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:linux] and [tag:ubuntu] if you are including `windows.h`?...

Comment: @LPs Read what I stated in my first  sentence. I did a crosscompile on Ubuntu aka Linux and my problem lies in the Linux crosscompile path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution to this problem probably lies right here:
[Cross compile tips for libraries](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW/Tips)

These are some tips and tricks for the cross compilation compiler mingw32 and the compilation of curl with my missing argument -DCURL_STATICLIB. I didn't test this out though because I solved the problem without curl.

Comment: But that's usually just the first step. Doing so you will run most probably into another linking problems like:
libcurld.lib(easy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function _win32_init
....
you can solve this ones by linking again:  wldap32.lib and Ws2_32.lib
http://blog.yastrebkov.com/2010/08/unresolved-externals-while-linking.html

Answer (score 2):

Cross-Compiling library Using `--prefix` you are defining the  the toplevel installation directory.

Libs will be placed into `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib`

Same thing for includes files they will be placed `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include`

Using `-L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/` you are pointing the wrong path for libraries and cross-compiler cannot find `libcurl`

To point to the correct include location you have to add `-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include` to your command.

At the end you compiled curl libs static only then you want to compile them statically: add `-static` to your command.

SO the correct command will be:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -static -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lcurl main.c -o main.exe
```

Comment: Tried it out but sadly it doesn't work :(. Have you any other idea ?

Comment: Where are libcurl.* installed? Is `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib` the correct path?

Comment: Yes it is there is a libcurl.a   and a libcurl.la

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not working this way. But thank  you for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [curls FAQ](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/FAQ#L1277):

> If you get linker error like "unknown symbol __imp__curl_easy_init
>   ..." you   have linked against the wrong (static) library.  If you
>   want to use the   libcurl.dll and import lib, you don't need any extra
>   CFLAGS, but use one of   the import libraries below. These are the
>   libraries produced by the various   lib/Makefile.* files:
>
> ```
>    Target:          static lib.   import lib for libcurl*.dll.
>    -----------------------------------------------------------
>    MingW:           libcurl.a     libcurldll.a
>    MSVC (release):  libcurl.lib   libcurl_imp.lib
>    MSVC (debug):    libcurld.lib  libcurld_imp.lib
>    Borland:         libcurl.lib   libcurl_imp.lib
> ```

Try path to linker `-lcurl_imp` or `-llibcurl_imp`

**Update**: Here is write flags on my Ubuntu with MinGW64:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o app.exe objects.a -Lexternals/curl-7.39.0/lib -llibcurl_imp
```

Why I use `libcurl_imp.lib` instead `libcurldll.a` as described in table above? Becouse I build curl with cmake which make `libcurl_imp.lib`. So you should check name of built library.

Comment: Tried faild. Tried again with recompiling library... failed.... . Nope I am gonna stop right here -.- . I am thinking that eventually I made something wrong with the configuration or compilation ? By the way I am using the library version 7.49. Something really interesting I stumbled upon is that if you call curl-config you get a bunch of compiler options that are interesting but didnt help in my case.